# NgRx not skipping 'successful' action on error

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have this effect:

```
  updateBook$ = createEffect(() =>
    this._actions$.pipe(
      ofType(START_UPDATE_BOOK),
      exhaustMap(action => this._api.updateBook({id: action.id}).pipe(
        map(data => UPDATE_BOOK({id: data.id})),
        catchError(error => of(HANDLE_ERROR({error})))
      )
    )
  ));
```

And this method in API service:

```
  updateBook(id: string): Observable<any> {
    const params = {
      id
    };
    return this.httpClient
      .get<any>(`${this._host}/${this.module}/api/${this.endpoint}/Delete`, {params});
  }
```

However, when the given ID is wrong and the server returns 400 Bad Request, the UPDATE_BOOK action is still being called (and HANDLE_ERROR shortly afterwards). Why does this happen and UPDATE_BOOK action isn't omitted? 
Thank you for any help provided.

UPDATE (**I forgot to define a reducer for one of the actions**): 
Actions defined like this:

```
export const START_UPDATE_BOOK = createAction(
  '[Books] Start update book',
  props<{id: string}>()
);

export const UPDATE_BOOK = createAction(
  '[Books] Update book',
  props<{id: string}>()
);

export const HANDLE_ERROR = createAction(
  '[Books] Handle Error',
  props<{error: string}>()
);
```

Reducer:

```
const bookReducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(START_UPDATE_BOOK),
  on(UPDATE_BOOK, (state, payload) => {
      const book: Book = state.books.find(el => el.Id === payload.id);
      book.Status = Status.PENDING;
      return {
        ...state,
      };
  }),
  on(HANDLE_ERROR, (state, payload) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      error: payload.error
    };
  })
);
```

Comment: How did you define those action type like `START_UPDATE_BOOK` and how you dispatch an action can you update your code please

Comment: Tony, I have updated the post. I forgot to add 1 action in reducer function. Now it goes straight into HANDLE_ERROR. Does 204 No Content count as error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems strange, if you have a reproduction I'm happy to take a look.

Can you verify:

- the server does in fact return a `400`
- do you use interceptors? If so, verify they don't map a `400` to a `200`

Comment: I forgot to add 1 action in reducer function :(. Now it goes straight into HANDLE_ERROR. Does 204 No Content count as error?

Comment: 204 is counted is a success - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204